# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0 Login with Lumen

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0, lumen

I writing a small application where I'm trying to get some Facebook information, but I can't manage to get the authentication to work.

At first I've setup the `AppServiceProvider` with:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(static::APP_ID, static::APP_SECRET);
```

Then In my view I just have a button which goes to the `auth` URL.
The `auth` route is using the `HomeController@index`, which contains the following:

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $helper = new FacegroupRedirectLoginHelper($request->url());

    if($session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect()) {
        dd($session);
    }

    return redirect($helper->getLoginUrl());
}
```

I've created my own `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` which extends the base class of Facebook. This has the following methods, just to leverage the Lumen `Session` implementation:

```
protected function storeState($state)
{
    Session::put(static::SESSION_KEY, $state);
}

protected function loadState()
{
    return $this->state = Session::get(static::SESSION_KEY, null);
}
```

This code is not working somehow, I've seen people doing this on the internet as well. What could be wrong? The session is always `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the people who are new with Lumen. In order to make the Session service working, you have to enable it in your `bootstrap/app.php` line 55 to line 61.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: as of Lumen 5.2 session support is completely removed as Lumen is evolving to a real stateless API framework..

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK V5 for Laravel Works Fine with Lumen you just have to change the Routing ... Here is how you configure and use LaravelFacebookSdk with Lumen

To use first

```
{
    "require": {
        "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "~3.0"
    }
}
```

Then in your bootstrap/app.php of lumen add

```
// Facebook Sdk Provider
$app->register('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider');
```

Then pubish the config ( Make sure you have config folder setup with lumen , By default it isn’t there )

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider"
```

The Main Step is to configure The Service provider and Laravel Facebook Sdk
By Default `LaravelFacebookSdk.php` and `LaravelUrlDetectionHandler.php` uses `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` . You will find those files in vendor src folder replace it with `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator` . And you are done . ( Be careful editing vendor src files **are not recommended** because it will be overwritten next time you call `composer update` or new version appears on composer repository . This is just a Quick fix for testing . Fork it, make your own repo or find a way )

Then you wil be able to use LaravelFacebookSdk in Lumen like this

```
$app->get('/user', function(SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk $fb){

    // Get basic info on the user from Facebook.
    try {

        $token = "your-access-token-here";

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);

        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

    // Convert the response to a `Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser` collection
    $facebook_user = $response->getGraphUser();

    var_dump($facebook_user);

});
```

Comment: The php artisan vendor:publish --provider="SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider"  gives me the following error : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\config_path() in /usr/share/nginx/amusement/vendor/sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk/src/LaravelFacebookSdk/LaravelFacebookSdkServiceProvider.php on line 22

Comment: config_path() error means there is no config folder . Create a Config folder and if you use config then dont forget to load it with $app->configure('myconfig');

Comment: @studentOfWeb do you know if this still works with Lumen 5.2? Session support is removed and all authentication should be handled with stateless  API tokens or headers..  https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade